# Why I can't access the itemName after I peform the price mapping in the stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

May I know does java stream allows us to access back the itemName from the subTtl list?
The reason of accessing itemName is because I want to output the data similar as below but the data will be form in the array format.
The expected output will be
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97fwW.png)

```
class Order{
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList();

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}


class Item{
    
    String name;
    double price;
    public Item(String name, double price) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Item() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Item i1 = new Item("Soap", 3.9);
        Item i2 = new Item("Plate", 15.9);
        Item i3 = new Item("Wok", 199.9);
        
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setItems( Arrays.asList( i1, i2, i3 ) );
        List<Item> items = order.getItems();
        List<Double> subTtl = items.stream().map(elem -> elem.price * 1.06).collect(Collectors.toList());
        subTtl.forEach(System.out::println);
        double ttl = subTtl.stream().mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue).summaryStatistics().getSum();
        System.out.println("Total Payment without tax: " + ttl);
        System.out.println("Total Payment: " + ttl * 1.10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a new data structure per say your row in the expected output and `map` to that data structure using a method which does all your computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itemName` is a member of `Item`. You could only guarantee access to the correct `itemName` from a stream/collection containing `Item`s. Its possible to get what you want but you'd have to start streaming from the `List<Item> items`. However to stream over a list and perform anything other than one main job would be considered a "side effect" (side effects are not "pure functions" and generally considered less than ideal).

So you'd ultimately have something like (untested):

```java
items.stream().foreach(item -> System.out.println(item.getName() 
+ "\t" + item.getPrice() 
+ "\t" + (item.getPrice() * 0.06) 
+ "\t" + (item.getPrice() * 1.06));
double grandTotal = items.stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum) * 1.06;
System.out.println("GRAND TOTAL:\t\t\t" + grandTotal);
double serviceTax = grandTotal * 0.1;
System.out.println("SERVICE TAX:\t\t\t" + serviceTax);
double totalPayment = grandTotal * 1.1;
System.out.println("TOTAL PAYMENT:\t\t\t" + totalPayment);
```

I've taken the liberty to add getters for the class variables that need to be exposed. I've also assumed the layout doesn't need to be exactly the same as your image layout - for that you'd want to use padded text to line things up correctly but that will be more effort than its likely worth but you may wish to amend depending on whether this is commercial/homework. I'd also consider encapsulating the methods for displaying the grand total, service tax and total payment so you can just call a single line function whose name is more along the lines of

```java
displayGrandTotal(items);
displayServiceTax(items);
displayTotalPayment(items);
```

Hopefully this is useful